# 4x4 grid challenge

Tags: logic-grid

You probably know the classic 3x3 grid challenge, where it’s about drawing one single line that touches all dots in the grid, with only 4 segments (3 turns) on the line.

Here’s a little drawing to understand what I mean:
[image]

I wonder if it’s possible to do this with a 4x4 grid and only 6 segments (5 turns) on the line?

Notice that it’s allowed to go outside the box, like I did above.

You can use this website do make the drawings online, [Dotty Grid Online](https://nrich.maths.org/dottyGrid/#/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer:

> Yes, there is a solution with 6 lines. 
>  [image: 6 line solution] 
>  Here is another one I found which isn't as pretty. 
>  [image: 6 line ugly solution]

Comment: Wow, cool. 2 solutions is even better!

Answer (score 2):

Since the 3x3 covers most of the 4x4, we only need to add to it with two lines.
[image: 4x4]

Comment: Oops. Seems like i was a little too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my edited answer with the tiny lines removed

> [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnikj.jpg)

Comment: Sorry should have made it more clear that you’re only allowed to draw one single line.

Comment: @Jdrupal As I explained, just take off the four tiny little lines and it is one single line. Problem was, the grid you provided didn't have two points where i needed them. I need points in between the points.

Comment: That’s the problem. I don’t think that counts, sorry.

Comment: @Jdrupal Sorry, my picture must have been too confusing for you. As I said you needed to imagine it without the tiny lines. I have edited the picture now so they are gone.

Comment: Ok, I don’t think you understand what I mean. According to the 4x4 grid that dot doesn’t exist and therefore it doesn’t really count, but anyway it’s an alternative solution :)